# Iterating backwards Multibyte String - C

Tags: c, c99, multibyte

I know I can iterate forwards through a multibyte string, in C, using mbrtowc(). But what if I wanted to iterate backwards; or in other words how do I find the previous valid multibyte character. I tried the following method and it at least partially works on my Ubuntu system using the default en_us.UTF-8 locale:

```
        char *str = "\xc2\xa2\xc2\xa1xyzwxfd\xc2\xa9", *tmp = NULL;
        wchar_t wc = 0;
        size_t ret = 0, width = 1;
        mbstate_t state = {0};

        //Iterate through 2 characters using mbrtowc()
        tmp = str;
        tmp += mbrtowc(&wc, tmp, MB_CUR_MAX, &state);
        tmp += mbrtowc(&wc, tmp, MB_CUR_MAX, &state);

        //This is a simplified version of my code. I didnt test this
        //exact code but this general idea did work.
        for(tmp--; (ret = mbrtowc(&wc, tmp, width, &state)) == (size_t)(-1) || ret == (size_t)(-2); width++, tmp--)
            if(width == MB_CUR_MAX) printf("error\n");

        printf("last multibyte character %lc\n", wc);
```

The idea is simple just iterate backwards by one byte until we find a valid multibyte character as defined by mbrtowc(). My question is can I rely on this to work for any possible multibyte locale or just encoding's with special properties. Also more specifically is mbstate_t being used incorrectly; I mean could the change in direction affect the validity of mbstate_t? Can I guarantee that 'ret' will only be (size_t)(-1) or (size_t)(-2) instead of either because I currently assume that 'ret' could be both depending on the definitions for an incomplete and invalid multibyte character.

Comment: If you are positive you only have to process UTF8 strings, then: the first byte of *any* UTF8 sequence is unique.

Comment: However, for legacy double-byte encodings, it's generally impossible to iterate backwards without actually starting from the beginning.

Comment: @RadLexus Thanks for the advice but unfortunately I cannot make that assumption.

Comment: @Joker_vD can you give me some specific examples?

Comment: @CMR-47: All character sets based on ISO/IEC 2022 have *shift state*, which means you need to parse the entire string from start to whatever position you are interested in. See [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022#ISO.2FIEC_2022_character_sets) of such character sets at the Wikipedia page, and the [shifting scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022#Code_structure) on that same page. Shift-JIS is not one of those, its name derives from another type of "shifting".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to deal with any theoretically-possible multibyte encoding, then it is not possible to iterate backwards. There is no requirement that a multibyte encoding have the property that no proper suffix of a valid multibyte sequence is a valid multibyte sequence. (As it happens, your algorithm requires an even stronger property, because you might recognize a multibyte sequence starting in the middle of one valid sequence and continuing into the next sequence.)

Also, you cannot predict (again, in general) the multibyte state if the multibyte encoding has shift states. If you back-up over a multibyte sequence which changes the state, you have no idea what the previous state was.

UTF-8 was designed with this in mind. It does not have shift states, and it clearly marks the octets (bytes) which can start a sequence. So if you know that the multibyte encoding is UTF-8, you can easily iterate backwards. Just scan backwards for a character not in the range 0x80-0xBF. (UTF-16 and UTF-32 are also easily iterated in either direction, but you need to read them as two-/four-byte code units, respectively, because a misaligned read is quite likely to be a correct codepoint.)

If you don't know that the multibyte encoding is UTF-8, then there is simply no robust algorithm to iterate backwards. All you can do is iterate forwards and remember the starting position *and mbstate* of each character.

Fortunately, these days there is really little reason to support multibyte encodings other than Unicode encodings.

Answer (score 0):

For UTF-8 you can take benefit of the [encoding property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) of the additional bytes following the first one:  the additional bytes of a multibyte chars (and only them) start with 10xx xxxx.

So if you go backward an a char c is so that `(c & 0xC0)==0x80` then you can skip it.

For other multibyte encoding you don't necessarily have such a simple solution as the lead and following bytes are in [ranges that overlap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding#CJK_multibyte_encodings).